# Unable to open a file using FileReader in java applet while the programs runs without any error in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, applet, filenotfoundexception, filewriter

I'm writing an applet. When i am running the code in command prompt it shows a file not found exception. The program is running pretty fine in Eclipse IDE. Can anyone tell what could be the error?

```java
Frame frame= new Frame();
FileDialog openfile= new FileDialog(frame,"Select a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
openfile.setVisible(true);
String file=openfile.getFile();
System.out.println(file);
try{
FileReader f= new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(f);
Scanner in=new Scanner(br);
while(in.hasNextInt()){
n=in.nextInt();
count++;
sum += n;
System.out.println(n);

}
System.out.println("Count:" + count);
```

Comment: When asking questions, you should provide a working piece of code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if the target file is not in the same directory as your application.

Use `String file = openfile.getDirectory() + File.separator + openfile.getFile();` to get the absolute path to the target file.

Comment: @Bahman...i have to upload this code on the server and the file will bw selected from the local computer...an now this exception comes up Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: acc
ess denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\ankit\workspace\applet test\src\c
opyit.txt" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:372)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
559)

Comment: Please be more precise: what do you mean "upload to server"?  Is the code supposed to run in webstart mode or as an applet?

Comment: Never wrote an applet myself so can't be sure.  But, IIRC, you need a certificate for the applet to be able to access local files from the sandbox.  Check [How to open/read/write a local file from an applet](http://faculty.kutztown.edu/spiegel/CSc421/SigningAnApplet.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the directory

```
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReader1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int sum=0,count=0,n;
        Frame frame= new Frame();
        FileDialog openfile= new FileDialog(frame,"Select a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        openfile.setVisible(true);
        String dir=openfile.getDirectory();
        String file = openfile.getFile();
        File ff = new File(dir+file);
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        Scanner in = null;
        System.out.println(dir+file);
        try{

            fr  = new FileReader(ff);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            in=new Scanner(br);
            while(in.hasNextInt()){
                n=in.nextInt();
                count++;
                sum += n;
                System.out.println(n);
            }
            System.out.println("Count:" + count);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception"+e);
        }finally{
            fr.close();
            br.close();
            in.close();
        }

    }
}
```